# Mysterious -2 rep for non-existent downvote to my question

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

My [reputation history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4012/doncherry?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2012-06-02%2010:17:19Z&page=10) shows:

[image]

The [post it links to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15563/can-pdf-thumbnail-previews-in-file-explorer-be-influenced), however, doesn't have any downvotes:

[image]

Neither is this downvote reflected in my https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation (a recalc didn't change anything):

```
-- 2011-04-20 rep 0     = 192       
 1     16684 (2)
 2     16692 (10)
```

Neither does the [timeline of that post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/15563/timeline) reveal any downvotes:

[image]

I don't care about the -2 rep, of course, but that seems to be some bug in the reputation system or at least something I don't understand at all. Any ideas or explanations? Should this be posted/migrated to meta.so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not a bug, the user who downvoted reversed his decision three days later, which is shown as an "undownvote" in the [reputation history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4012/doncherry?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2012-06-02%2010:17:19Z&page=10):

[image: undownvote on April 23'11]

I don't know why this isn't reflected in the [timeline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/15563/timeline), I guess it still uses the old, less fine-grained reputation display approach.